Custom React Widget built using webpack not working
I want to build a custom react widget using reactjs. Below is my webpack config-


import path from "path";
import { Configuration, ProvidePlugin } from "webpack";
import CopyWebpackPlugin from "copy-webpack-plugin";
import Dotenv from "dotenv-webpack";
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from "mini-css-extract-plugin";

const config: Configuration = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: "./src/index.tsx",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.tsx?$/,
        use: {
          loader: "ts-loader",
          options: {
            compilerOptions: {
              noEmit: false,
            },
          },
        },
        exclude: /node_modules|\.d\.ts$/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.d\.ts$/,
        loader: "ignore-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/, // File extension to match
        use: [
          "@svgr/webpack",
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
          },
        ], // SVG loader (using @svgr/webpack to convert SVG to React components)
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
    fallback: {
      assert: require.resolve("assert"),

      buffer: require.resolve("buffer"),

      stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),

      crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),

      zlib: require.resolve("browserify-zlib"),

      http: require.resolve("stream-http"),

      https: require.resolve("https-browserify"),

      vm: require.resolve("vm-browserify"),

      path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),

      os: require.resolve("os-browserify/browser"),
    },
  },
  output: {
    library: "ZebecCard",
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    umdNamedDefine: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [{ from: "public" }],
    }),
    new Dotenv(),
    new ProvidePlugin({
      process: "process/browser",
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "bundle.css",
      chunkFilename: "bundle.css",
    }),
  ],
};

export default config;



I have used UMD as library target and output module name as ZebecCard.
Below is my index.tsx file-


import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./globals.css";
import App from "./App";
import { SolanaWalletAdapterProvider } from "./contexts/SolanaWalletAdapterContext";
import { store } from "./store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import ConnectWallet from "./components/wallet-connection/ConnectWallet";
import SignTransaction from "./components/SignTransaction";
import { StepProvider } from "./contexts/StepContext";
import { FormProvider } from "./contexts/FormContext";
import { initializeSocket } from "./lib/websocket.service";
import { Toasts } from "./shared/toasts";

initializeSocket();
window.Buffer = window.Buffer || require("buffer").Buffer;
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("zebec-card-terminal") as HTMLElement
);

export const init = (config: any) => {
  console.log("here is this config", config);
  root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <SolanaWalletAdapterProvider>
          <StepProvider>
            <FormProvider>
              <App />
              <ConnectWallet />
              <SignTransaction />
              <Toasts />
            </FormProvider>
          </StepProvider>
        </SolanaWalletAdapterProvider>
      </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
};
// init({});



I built using the command-
"build:webpack": "rm -rf public/widget && webpack --mode production && mkdir -p public/widget && cp -r dist public/widget/ && rm -rf dist ",


Blockquote

The built is successfull and I deployed the app. Now I want to use the widget in other apps using following -


....

useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script")
    script.src = "./assets/widget/dist/bundle.js"
    script.async = true
    document.head.appendChild(script)

    return () => {
      document.head.removeChild(script)
    }
  }, [])
  useEffect(() => {
    // Create a <link> element
    const link = document.createElement("link")
    link.href = "./assets/widget/dist/bundle.css"
    link.rel = "stylesheet"

    // Append the <link> element to the <head> of the document
    document.head.appendChild(link)

    // Clean up function to remove the <link> element when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      document.head.removeChild(link)
    }
  }, [])
  return (
    <Layout pageTitle="WarpGate - Bridge" implementContainer={false}>
      <ZebecCard init={{ config: { name: "upendra dhamala" } }} />

      <div id="zebec-card-terminal" className=""></div>
      
      ...



I am facing issues in using this and outputs some errors. However when I simply try to use widget using script tags only i.e for css and js, then its working. In that case my index.tsx will simple uncomment init({}) and after that build. However as I want to pass the config too it's compulsory for me to build as umd module library target and for that I have to comment out init({}). I need to have config because I need to a way to pass .env values. Here is the repo link- CardWidget.
